image and text content in components.html()
I want to display an image and some text below it, using components.html(). But text is not getting displayed below the image. Following is the code:
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

components.html(
    '<html><body>' +
    '<a href="https://i.ibb.co/0j2mc7K/4-NPTEL.png" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">' +
    '<img src="https://i.ibb.co/0j2mc7K/4-NPTEL.png" style="width:600px;">' +
    '<div style="color: rgb(81, 0, 12); font-size: 23px; font-family: \'Book Antiqua\';">Title</div>' +
    '<div style="margin-top: 15px; color: rgb(81, 0, 12); font-size: 17px; font-family: \'Book Antiqua\';">Some Description</div></a></body></html>'
)

The same structure works in plain html:
<html>
<body>
    <a href="https://i.ibb.co/0j2mc7K/4-NPTEL.png" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0j2mc7K/4-NPTEL.png" style="width:600px;">
        <div style="color: rgb(81, 0, 12); font-size: 23px; font-family: 'Book Antiqua';">
            Title
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 15px; color: rgb(81, 0, 12); font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Book Antiqua';">
            Some Description
        </div>
    </a>
</body>
</html>

What can be the issue with the streamlit components.html() code?

That's because the iframe (created by streamlit) is too short for the texts to show up.
Actually, the html component has a height parameter :
    height : int
            The height of the frame in CSS pixels. Defaults to 150.


You need to increase it :
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

components.html(
    "<html><body>"
    + '<a href="https://i.ibb.co/0j2mc7K/4-NPTEL.png" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">'
    + '<img src="https://i.ibb.co/0j2mc7K/4-NPTEL.png" style="width:600px;">'
    + "<div style=\"color: rgb(81, 0, 12); font-size: 23px; font-family: 'Book Antiqua';\">Title</div>"
    + "<div style=\"margin-top: 15px; color: rgb(81, 0, 12); font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Book Antiqua';\">Some Description</div></a></body></html>",
    height=500, # << here
)

SN: No need to concatenate (+). You can pass the plain html as a multiline string.
